# Extract text from file in Linux: specific line; between 2 different patterns

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a bunch of text files, all with the same structure, and I need to extract a specific piece in a specific line.

I can easily extract the line with awk:

```
awk 'NR==23' blast_out.txt

CP046310.1 Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...  787     0.0
```

But I don't want the whole line, rather just the part between the first space on the left (after `CP046310.1`) and the double space on the right (before `787`). The final output should be:

```
Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...
```

I tried several combination of awk and grep but cannot find the correct one to extract this specific pattern.

Comment: Do you have double spaces or tabs anywhere else on the line and, if so, do you care about preserving them in the output?

Comment: please update the question with the `several combination of awk and grep` you tried and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, nullifying 1st, 2nd last field and last field, then globally substituting starting and ending space with NULL, then printing the line.

```
awk '{$1=$NF=$(NF-1)="";gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***OR*** to run it on 23rd line change it to:

```
awk 'FNR==23{$1=$NF=$(NF-1)="";gsub(/^ +| +$/,"");print;exit}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Going through fields and printing values which are required as per need.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<(NF-1);i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==(NF-2)?ORS:OFS)}}' Input_file
```

***OR*** on 23rd line try following:

```
awk 'FNR==23{for(i=2;i<(NF-1);i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==(NF-2)?ORS:OFS)};exit}' Input_file
```

Comment: Note: I have also put `exit` in 2nd OR codes to make sure we exit early and we need not to read whole file and we save sometime in it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you can use this solution:

```sh
sed -En '23s/^[^ ]+ |  .*$//gp' file

Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
 awk 'NR == 23 {gsub(/^[^ ]+ |  .*$/, ""); print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you ask, you want to extract the fields from the second (included) to the second-last (excluded).
I would go with:

```
awk ' FNR==23 {for (i = 2; i < NF - 2; i++) { printf("%s ", $i) }; printf("%s\n", $i); exit }' file_path
```

An example with the line you posted:

```
$ echo "CP046310.1 Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...  787     0.0" | awk '{for (i = 2; i < NF - 2; i++) { printf("%s ", $i) }; printf("%s\n", $i); exit }'
$ Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...
```

I assume that `chromosome,...` does not contains spaces and you have only single spaces separating the fields you want to extract. If the second condition is not true, those extra spaces are removed.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
echo "CP046310.1 Lactobacillus jensenii strain FDAARGOS_749 chromosome,...  787     0.0"|perl -ne 'm/ (.*?)  /; print $1'
```